# IE11 - Using Google Charts in Angular 7 gives syntax error

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, google-visualization, internet-explorer-11

I am using Google Charts library in Angular 7. It works well in FF, Safari and Chrome. However, when I try to see it in IE11, I see this error in console.

```
SCRIPT 1002: Syntax Error 
File: vendor.js, Line: 173392, Column: 1
```

When I click on that error in the console, it takes me to this screen and the cursor stops at the keyword `class`

[image: Class Error with Google Charts]

I am not sure, why the charts are not rendering. I am able to browse the Google Charts website just fine in IE11.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Don't use ES6 Google Charts Module, it's not supported in IE. I'm using angular8 and I followed [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/different-way-of-implementing-google-column-chart-in-angular-7) to use google charts. It works well in IE, shows no error. You can also refer to [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-charts).

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 doesn't support ES6 classes.

Find the tsconfig.json file and change the "target" property from "es6" to "es5" or lower.

[More info](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class)

Comment: hmm.. I did have it set to es5. But still it didn't work. Here's the tsconfig.json `{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}`

Comment: You're using ngx-charts?

Comment: Using "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.3"  and devDependency is  "google-charts": "^2.0.0", I think this is the npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-charts

Comment: This is a ES5 version: https://github.com/mmathias01/google-charts/blob/master/dist/googleCharts.js

Comment: Use this instead of the ES6.

Comment: I have these files in the dist folder. `googleCharts.esm.js`, `googleCharts.js` and `googleCharts.min.js`.   How can I force it to use `googleCharts.js` (which looks like the es5 version) ?

Comment: It should be implemented automatically: https://github.com/mmathias01/google-charts/blob/master/rollup.config.js

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If it's supposed to roll up automatically, why would IE11 give an error on ES6 google charts?